# Making a method wait button press

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, wait

My method has to return AFTER the user presses a Button. After some researches, I thought this would work:

The method itself:

```
public Aluno getAlunoFromUser() throws InterruptedException
{
    //Wait to be notified from ActionListener
    synchronized(this)
    {
        this.wait();
    }

    //return
    return null;
}
```

The ActionListener:

```
Button.addActionListener( 
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    this.notify();
                }
            });
```

But the program is freezing. I want to know how do I fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't work as you're freezing the Swing event thread. One solution is to use a background thread to do your waiting. Another is to have your method change the model's *state*, and then when the button is pressed, change the model's state again, and update your view, your GUI based on these state changes. I prefer the latter unless your code runs a long-running process and will require a background thread regardless.

For a more detailed answer, you may wish to tell us more details about your problem including just what behavior specifically you're trying to achieve.

---

**Edit**  You state in a comment:

> Ok. getAlunoFromUser() opens a new window (which can be considered a dialog) and the user has to put some values in some JTextFields. When Button is pressed, I take those values and create an Aluno object with them, and return this Aluno object to the main window, so I can store it. (in the original code, getAlunoFromUser has more methods, but I deleted them to make it better to visualize)

For this why not simply use a modal JDialog or a JOptionPane (which really is nothing more than a pre-made modal JDialog)? This way you can close the dialog when the user presses the create Aluno button, and then the calling code can query the dialog-based code for the Aluno object.

---

**Edit 2**  For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AlunoExample {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("AlunoExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
   private DialogPanel dialogPanel = new DialogPanel();

   public MainPanel() {
      field.setEditable(false);
      field.setFocusable(false);

      add(new JLabel("Aluno:"));
      add(field);
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Create Aluno") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MainPanel.this,
                  dialogPanel, "Dialog", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
               String name = dialogPanel.getNameText();
               int value = dialogPanel.getValue();
               Aluno aluno = new Aluno(name, value);
               field.setText(aluno.toString());
            }

         }
      }));
   }
}

class DialogPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(5);
   private JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(
         new SpinnerNumberModel(50, 0, 100, 1));

   public DialogPanel() {
      add(new JLabel("Name:"));
      add(nameField);
      add(new JLabel("Value:"));
      add(spinner);
   }

   public String getNameText() {
      return nameField.getText();
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return ((Integer) spinner.getValue()).intValue();
   }
}

class Aluno {
   private String name;
   private int value;

   public Aluno(String name, int value) {
      this.name = name;
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue(int value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Aluno [name=" + name + ", value=" + value + "]";
   }

}
```

Comment: I want the method to **wait** for a signal that says _"button was clicked, now return something!"_ so I have to use wait(), right? How do I use wait, but not freezing? Just like JDialogs do, they wait the user press OK, so they return a String.

Comment: @user2489690: no you don't have to use `wait()`. Please tell me more about just what you're trying to return, more about what ***specifically*** you want the user to see and experience. Tell me things like, "If the user types in "blue" and then presses the "next" button, I want xxx to happen.

Comment: Ok. **getAlunoFromUser()** opens a new window (which can be considered a dialog) and the user has to put some values in some JTextFields. When Button is pressed, I take those values and create an **Aluno** object with them, and **return** this Aluno object to the main window, so I can store it. (in the original code, getAlunoFromUser has more methods, but I deleted them to make it better to visualize)

Comment: I would use Dialog, but there are 3 inputs, I don't to use 3 Dialogs, its kinda ugly.

Comment: @user2489690: No one said anything about using 3 dialogs! Just use one dialog with three input components on it.

Comment: @user2489690: see code example for what I mean. Please understand that you can pass JPanels with complex GUI's into JOptionPanes or JDialogs.

Comment: lool your program is really cool! so many other ways to do somethings, i really liked it =) I really didn't know I could add a panel to a dialog o.o Tnks for not downvoting me =)

Comment: one question: how to I put a layout to this dialogPanel? **GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());** isnt working...

Comment: @user2489690: I would avoid using GroupLayout since it is a very difficult layout to use by hand. Instead I would do what I normally do with most all my GUI's: nest JPanels each using one of the more simple to use layouts. If you run into problems with this, ask a new question on it, but post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) with the questino.